# SQL: How to compute the the last transaction without a refund?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a transactions table such as this:

```
Transaction
-----------
id
customer
product_id
date_purchased
amount
```

A positive amount denotes a purchase and a negative amount denotes a refund. How can I query this table for the last purchase that doesn't have a matching refund?

For example:

```
1, jack, 10, 10/10/2015, $10
2, jack, 10, 10/11/2015, -$10
3, jack, 10, 10/12/2015, $10
4, jack, 10, 10/13/2015, $10
5, jack, 10, 10/14/2015, -$10
```

If I run my desired query I should get the row with id 4.
Every negative amount is a targeted towards the earliest non refunded positive amount.

If it makes a difference, I am using postgresql.

Comment: Why would it be 4 instead of 3 (or 1 for that matter)?  What ties the refunds to the original purchase other than the dollar amounts being the same?

Comment: how do you know that the `14` refund is for the `13` purchase and not `12`?

Comment: Siyal, the purchase price. Every negative amount is a targeted towards the earliest non refunded positive amount.

Comment: You want the `where`, `order by` and `limit` clauses.

Comment: What happens when the amounts do not have the same absolute value?